# Creating a tablespace in postgresql on a mounted volume

Tags: postgresql, centos, centos7, chown

I am trying to create a tablespace in postgres on a mounted volume, but I am getting ownership problems.

I am doing something like:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/postgresql
sudo mkdir /mnt/postgresql/space
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /mnt/postgresql
```

Then, as the posgres superuser (`sudo -u postgres psql`), I am using the following command :

```
CREATE TABLESPACE myspace LOCATION '/mnt/postgresql/space';
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "/mnt/postgresql/space": Operation not permitted
```

I am using psql 9.2.24 with CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908.

Why the PostgreSQL system user could not set permissions on directory that it is owned ?

Comment: try: `chmod -R 700 /mnt/postgresql`

Comment: As pointed by @wildplasser `chmod -R 700 /mnt/postgresql` solve this issue

Comment: Do not use PostgreSQL 9.2 if you care about your data at all.